# Creating an insert statement to copy existing data from a SQL table

Tags: sql

I need to provide a user access to 170 different department codes. The UserAccess table contains the permissions and to give the access I just have to input a new line with an employee ID in the UserId column and a department code in the DepartmentCode column. The problem is I don’t want to manually enter 170 different insert statements. I’m trying to work out how to copy an existing user who has already the access to all the department codes.

dbo.Departments

- DepartmentCode (PK, char(5), not null)
- Description (varchar(50), null)

dbo.UserAccess

- UserId (varchar(10), not null)
- DepartmentCode (FK, char(5), not null)

Comment: How about something like `insert into dbo.Departments (column 1, column2) select (column 1, column2) from dbo.UserAccess where yourcondition=whatever;` ? Looks like quite a standard insert from another table and some where-Clauses, see f.e. [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will insert a user id with all the departments:

```
insert into useraccess (userid, departmentcode)
   select @userid, departmentcode
   from departments;
```

If you want to copy departments from an existing user:

```
insert into useraccess (userid, departmentcode)
   select @userid, ua.departmentcode
   from useraccess ua
   where ua.userid = @existing_userid;
```

Comment: I think it's close. Do you know how I would modify it if I want to insert a new employee ID - e.g. 375000, 170 times with 170 different dept codes. In the useraccess table there is already an existing employee with 170 dept codes who I'd like to copy. E.g there is 170 lines, the userid is copied onto all the lines, but the dept codes will be different on each line.